# Vertical space before list environment

Tags: spacing, lists

I use list environments for short text. In `myitem` environment I define new space between items. 
How I can reduce vertical space before first  item? This space is bigger than between paragraphs.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \newenvironment{myitem}{\begin{itemize}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{-5.0cm}
    \setlength{\itemindent}{0.0cm}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
     \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}     
     {\end{itemize}}

 \begin{document}
 \lipsum[1]
 \lipsum[2]
 \begin{myitem}
 \item lorem ipsum dolor  lorem ipsum dolor  lorem ipsum dolor  lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor 
 \item lorem ipsum dolor
 \item lorem ipsum dolor
 \item lorem ipsum dolor
 \end{myitem}
  \lipsum[3]
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's always `\vspace{negative length}`...

Comment: `\usepackage{enumitem}...\begin{itemize}[nosep]...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not easy to do directly and the best and simplest interface is the package `enumitem`.  Here you can set-up `mylist` (I prefer that name to `myitem`) as a copy of `itemize` with maximum list depth 1, bullet labels, a specified leftmargin and no vertical spacing via:

```
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=1cm,nosep}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=1cm,nosep}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\begin{mylist}
\item lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem
  ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor
\item lorem ipsum dolor
\item lorem ipsum dolor
\item lorem ipsum dolor
\end{mylist}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I add `enumitem` in preambula and definition of `mylist`. But when I compile my MWE, i receive error: `Package keyval Error: nosep undefined \item`

Comment: Make sure you have an up-to-date version of `enumitem` - this feature was introduced in version 3.4 - the current version is 3.5.2 or so.